# Drag only one sprite in a group with the mouse

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite

The problem that I cannot figure how to sort is that when I drag a piece over another the second piece also is dragged along with the first.  I have tried several ways to limit the mouse selection to one piece at at time, but all have failed.  Can anyone help - no doubt there is a simple way!  The code shorn of all my failed attempts follows:

```
   # In main loop:
   # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               mouse_held = True
           if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
               mouse_held = False

       # Update pieces that are in a sprite.Group()
       pieces.update(mouse_held)

    # In sprite class:
    def update(self, mouse_held):
        if mouse_held == True:
            self.mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if self.rect.collidepoint(self.mouse_coordinates) == True:
                self.rect.centerx = self.mouse_coordinates[0]
                self.rect.centery = self.mouse_coordinates[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your question is fairly difficult but by doing all of this you should be able t achieve what you want.**

You should change your `sprite` class to have a new variable of type int named `depth` (the higher the value the 'deeper' it is).

Considering you have a list of all the sprite objects you want to check for clicks called `spriteList` you should add this:

```
from operator import attrgetter
```

then change these lines:

```
   if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           mouse_held = True
```

to:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    sprites = []
    for sprite in spriteList:
        if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)  ==  True:
            sprites.append(sprite)
    active = min(lists, key=attrgetter('depth'))
    mouse_held = True
```

You should replace the `sprite`'s `update` function to:

```
def update(self):
    self.mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if self.rect.collidepoint(self.mouse_coordinates) == True:
         self.rect.centerx = self.mouse_coordinates[0]
         self.rect.centery = self.mouse_coordinates[1]
```

And finally when you want to update the sprite's position simply type:

```
if mouse_held:
    active.update()
```

Comment: Thanks I wouldn't have found that solution quickly.  For completeness sake, I had to adapt/modify code:                
                try:
                    active = min(sprites, key=attrgetter('rect'))
                except ValueError: 
                    print('Empty place selected, so sprite list is empty')
and:
        if mouse_held:
            try:
                active.update()
            except UnboundLocalError:
                print('active not set, to due to previous exception')